# How can I bake the material from cycles render (with diffuse, glossy, emission, transparent, glass and translucent nodes) and use it next time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

How can I bake the material from cycles render (with diffuse, glossy, emission, transparent, glass and translucent nodes) and use it next time? According to http://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html I added in every material an image texture and then pressed the *Bake* button, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is not working? Could you add a screenshot of your material setup? What do you mean by "use it next time"? As far as I know, you can bake only 1 image texture at time whit the built-in function.

Comment: I mean I would like to know how to use the baked image as material for next time if I want to render